# Mostrar contenido únicamente al interactuar con href

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo un código un poco rebuscado. La idea era hacer una estructura dinámica para una lista de x pack con z ejercicios.

La estructura y el código me funcionan muy bien, el problema que tengo es que el contenido lo tengo puesto directamente en el cuerpo y con un script cargo las imágenes y vídeos. Entonces cuando entro en la página me salen las imágenes y el vídeo sin contenido (obviamente).

Lo que me gustaría es que no salieran esas imágenes vacías ni ese reproductor de vídeo vacío.

He probado a utilizar `<template>` pero luego al seleccionar el ejercicio no me cargaba el contenido.

Éste es el código:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
            <img id="id-title" alt="" style="text-align:center">
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <img class="img_ejercicios" id="id-imagen" alt="" >
            <img class="img_ejercicios" id="id-imagen2" alt="" >
        </div>
        <br>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <video id="id-video" controls></video>
</div>

<script>
        var direccion = "";
        $("a[class='dropdown-item ejercicio']").each(function( index, element ) {
            $(this).click(function (){
            var temporal = $( this ).attr("href").split("#")[1] ;
            title = "../packs/" + temporal + "/title.png";
            direccion = "../packs/" + temporal + "/imagen1.png";
            direccion2 = "../packs/" + temporal + "/imagen2.png";
            video = "../packs/" + temporal + "/video.mp4";
                $("#id-title").attr("src", title).css({"width": "90%"});
                $("#id-imagen").attr("src", direccion).css({"width": "35%"});
                $("#id-imagen2").attr("src", direccion2).css({"width": "35%"});
                $("#id-video").attr("src", video);
            console.log(direccion);
          })

        });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Necesitas que se muestren o se oculten todos los elementos uno a uno o en bloque? ¿Tienes algún estilo que pudiera romperse si encapsulo todo ese HTML dentro de un `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lo que me gustaría es que no saliera esas imágenes vacías ni ese reproductor de vídeo vacío

Quizá sería mejor ocultar todo el contenido mientras no lo necesites con `display: none`:

```
<div id="encapsulado" style="display: none;">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img id="id-title" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img class="img_ejercicios" id="id-imagen" alt="" />
    <img class="img_ejercicios" id="id-imagen2" alt="" />
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <video id="id-video" controls></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

De modo que cuando muestres el contenido solo debes cambiar el modo de mostrar el elemento a `block`:

```
<script>
  var direccion = "";
  $("a[class='dropdown-item ejercicio']").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).click(function() {
      let temporal = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];
      title = "../packs/" + temporal + "/title.png";
      direccion = "../packs/" + temporal + "/imagen1.png";
      direccion2 = "../packs/" + temporal + "/imagen2.png";
      video = "../packs/" + temporal + "/video.mp4";
      $("#id-title").attr("src", title).css({width: "90%"});
      $("#id-imagen").attr("src", direccion).css({width: "35%"});
      $("#id-imagen2").attr("src", direccion2).css({width: "35%"});
      $("#id-video").attr("src", video);
      console.log(direccion);
      /* Mostramos el elemento */
      $('#encapsulado').show();
    });
  });
</script>
```